# ng2-file-upload: How to change the form-data name for file upload

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, form-data, ng2-file-upload

I am currently using this code for file upload (Angular 2+):

```
upload() {
  let inputEl: HTMLInputElement = this.inputEl.nativeElement;
  let fileCount: number = inputEl.files.length;
  let formData = new FormData();
  if (fileCount > 0) { // a file was selected
      for (let i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
          formData.append('files', inputEl.files.item(i));
      }
      this.http.post(mySecretUrl, formData, {observe: 'response'}).subscribe(err => this.handleError(err), resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });
  }
}
```

With html:

```
<input #fileInput type="file" [multiple]="true" id="file-upload" size="60">
```

This works fine, but I wanted to use the ng2-file-upload because of all the extra goodies that comes along with that package.

When I enter my code for ng2-file-upload and try to upload I get a 500 error. I am 100% sure the problem is the key name 'files' which you will find in this line in the old code:

```
formData.append('files', inputEl.files.item(i));
```

How can I add/change the form-data key name to 'files' when using ng2-file-upload?

This is btw my code for ng2-file-upload:

```
    function readBase64(file): Promise<any> {
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    var future = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
        resolve(reader.result);
      }, false);

      reader.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
        reject(event);
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    return future;


    }

    const URL = 'mySecretUrl';

    private uploader:FileUploader = new FileUploader({
      url: URL, 
      disableMultipart:true
    });

    public hasBaseDropZoneOver:boolean = false;
    fileObject: any;

    public fileOverBase(e:any):void {
      this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e; 
    }

    public onFileSelected(event: EventEmitter<File[]>) {
      const file: File = event[0];

      console.log(file);

      readBase64(file)
        .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
    }
```

And the html:

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple (onFileSelected)="onFileSelected($event)"  />
```

EDIT:

I guess the answer to my question is:

```
    public uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
        ...
        itemAlias: 'files'
        ...
    })
```

...But I still get a 500 (internal server error) when I try to upload...

Answer (score -2):

500 error usually occurs if there is a problem on the server side. Try to see if your API endpoint is configured correctly.